# json.loads() is returning a unicode object instead of a dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode, fabric

I'm reading in json from a file on a remote server using fabric:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

output = StringIO()
get(file_name, output)

output = output.getvalue()
```

The value of `output` is now:

`'"{\\n    \\"status\\": \\"failed\\", \\n    \\"reason\\": \\"Record already 
exists.\\"\\n}"'`

When I try to parse this string to a dictionary using `json.loads(output)` its returns the unicode object `u'{\n    "status": "failed", \n    "reason": "Record already exists."\n}'` rather than a dictionary.

I've come up with a fairly bad fix, just passing the new unicode object back into json.loads():

`json.loads(json.loads(output))`

Is there any way other solution to this?

Cheers

Comment: If the data given is a string of json string, what's the problem with the approach? I think `json.loads(json.loads(..))` is a fine fix.. Aren't you worrying a little too much?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your data is escaped.

```
json.loads(output.decode('string-escape').strip('"'))
```

should give you desired results:

```
Out[12]: {'reason': 'Record already exists.', 'status': 'failed'}
```

Comment: Note this will only work correctly if `output` is a Python-byte-string-encoding of the JSON string, not if if it is double-JSON. There are differences between the two string formats—although none of them are visible from the example data above so it's impossible to say which is the correct approach. I would suspect double-JSON is more likely than JSON-in-Pybytestring though.

Answer (score 17):

The solution here would be to figure out why your file is being doubly JSON encoded in the first place, but given that data passing it through `json.loads` twice is the right approach.

Comment: Great, in my case I was inserting the json data into MariaDB by first using `json.dumps(my_data)` then within the `INSERT` query I was using MariaDB's `JSON_QUOTE` method, which does kind of `json.dumps`. Therefore, it was encoding it twice. Your answer helped me to go into the right track.